# Can't watch realmObjects in debug (Android Studio)

Tags: android, realm

I recently started using Realm. The problem is sometimes I have to use dubug mode to solve some bugs.

Thing is realmObjects always appear to have `null` fields in watch. On the other hand, if I log their values, they appear to be correct and not null.

What is going on here?

Comment: I don't know Realm, but maybe you are trying see a "lazy" field value?

Comment: Hmmm, it appears that must be it. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that field is not lazy. Lazy objects are loaded when they are retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **evaluate expression** feature of the debugger for now as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424010/3736955).