# Android Realm - debugging

Tags: android, debugging, realm

I want to see the values of Realm object variables

### For Example:

```
Student (int studentID, ArrayList <Subject> subjectList)

Subject (int subjectID, String subjectName)
```

I want to see the names of subjects in a student object when debugging using Android Studio.

**Where should I look in android studio debug window to find a student's the subjects list?**

Comment: run debugger it will automatically open debugger window

Comment: of course! after opening the debugger window where can I see values for subjects list? this is specific to Realm btw.

Comment: you can put breakpoint on line where you want to see the values

Comment: No. when I expand the student object's tree view in debugger window , Realm object shows subject list = 0. but in somewhere in that student object it stores subject list. I want to know where should I look in that student object to find its subject list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realm proxies your model objects and is a zero-copy storage system so in order to inspect the value of a field you need to use the **evaluate expression** feature of the debugger.

We are considering the possibility to write a plugin for the debugger to show the values directly, but that is still at an investigation stage.

Comment: Evaluate expression for realmResults.get(position).Name gives me null yet it is not. What to do?

Comment: Not working for met either  Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(MapCity.class).findAll(); returns a list of entites with null field-values (and they are not)

Comment: Still investigation stage?

Comment: We should all ditch Realm. It is the worst piece of software I've had to deal with. It fails us every single day for one reason or another. Not being able to properly debug our applications is not inconvenient, it's just unacceptable.

Comment: we are encountering this problem right now lol. and it's a real pain.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly do like that.

this my approach.

```
 List<FooObject> messages = realm.copyFromRealm(value);
```

And you can see in debugger values from messages.

Full Code

```
realm.where(FooObject.class).equalTo(FooObject.id, id).findAllAsync().asObservable()
            .filter(new Func1<RealmResults<FooObject>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(RealmResults<FooObject> message) {
                    return message.isLoaded();
                }
            }).subscribe(new SimpleObserver<RealmResults<FooObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    super.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(RealmResults<FooObject> value) {
                    super.onNext(value);
                    List<FooObject> messages = realm.copyFromRealm(value);
                    RLog.d(TAG, "Messages");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    super.onError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public String getTag() {
                    return TAG;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stheto from FaceBook. You will be able to see dynamic changes and all table etc. here is the link : https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm

I will explain  here: 
 import the lib from gradle with

```
>  compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
>  compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.1.0'
```

then in a class extends Application (dont forget to notify the manifest about your class :

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        android:name=".YourClassName"
```

then add this

```
public class YourClassName extends Application {
...
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     Stetho.initialize(
                    Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                            .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                            .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                            .build());
```

finnaly open chrome on this url

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

And click on inspect. Go on Ressources then on Web Sql. You will be able to see your db like that
 [image]

Comment: did the trick: android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"